# How to reload a UiView in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I want to reload data present in UiView.
I often use this code for reloading data present in tableview:

```
tableview.reloadData
```

Is there any way to reload data in uiView just like tableView?

Comment: In general, a `UIView` doesn't have "data", or it doesn't know that it has "data". If you think the text of a label is "data", then to reload it, just set the text of the label again.

Comment: @Sweeper i am setting text of a label as data which is fetched from json.in this case how can i set the text of the label again?

Comment: `label.text = "Some Text"`? You might want to re-fetch the json first.

Comment: @Sweeper i am doing the same ,but it is not setting the data in the label on running for first time but when i visit the view again after going back,then the data is present.so my main concern is to load data so that it is updated instantly

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. Typical "complex" views that might display large amounts of data (like `UITableView` or `UIPickerView`) use a *data source* protocol that allows them to fetch data on demand. In this case, you need to inform the view that new / modified data is available, hence call `reloadData`. Then, the view will ask the data source for the data to be displayed.

Primitive views (like `UILabel`) just provide a property (like `text`) which you need to set / update, and the view will then redisplay the data.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to introduce the [`View Drawing Cycle`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html) here.

> The UIView class uses an `on-demand drawing model` for presenting content. When a view `first` appears on the screen, the system asks it to `draw its content`. The system `captures a snapshot of this content` and uses that snapshot as the view’s visual representation. If you never change the view’s content, the view’s drawing code may never be called again. The snapshot image is `reused` for most operations involving the view. If you do change the content, you `notify` the system that the view has changed. The view then repeats the process of drawing the view and capturing a snapshot of the new results.

When the contents of your view change, you do not redraw those changes directly. Instead, you `invalidate the view` using either the `setNeedsDisplay` or `setNeedsDisplayInRect:` method. These methods tell the system that the contents of the view changed and need to be redrawn at the next opportunity. The system waits until the end of the current run loop before initiating any drawing operations. This delay gives you a chance to invalidate multiple views, add or remove views from your hierarchy, hide views, resize views, and reposition views all at once. All of the changes you make are then reflected at the same time.

If you change these [properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH5-SW9) for the view, you don't have to trigger `setNeedsDisplay()` or `setNeedsDisplay(_:)`. If you do want to do so in some cases, you can always force the contents of a view to be redrawn by calling the `setNeedsDisplay()` or `setNeedsDisplay(_:)` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

self.tableView.reloadData()
or
tableView?.reloadData()

Comment: Question is about reloading views that are *not* a table view.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are fetching the JSON data from the server which is an async task and you are setting the data in the label before the server give response to you, which looks like data not populated in the label. Use [escaping closure](https://medium.com/swiftcommmunity/what-do-mean-escaping-and-nonescaping-closures-in-swift-d404d721f39d) to update your data in the label after server gives response to you.